# Realm error - _constructor must be of type 'function', got (undefined)

Tags: react-native, mobile, realm, local-storage, realm-mobile-platform

I am trying to setup Realm DB locally with my react native application but there seems to be an error that I cannot figure out a reason for. I have followed the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest) and the guide [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sI64vaHF98&t=0s&list=PLRXaEJmfbSuhuKe2LNvjwIzKY3bMIW1U-&index=2).

My Code.

```
import Realm from 'realm';

export const ConfigSchema = {
    name: 'Config',
    primaryKey: 'key',
    properties: {
        key: 'string',
        value: 'string'
    }
};

export const databaseOptions = {
    path: 'myappreactnative.realm',
    schema: [ConfigSchema],
    schemaVersion: 0
};

export const insertNewConfig = (newConfig) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Realm.open(databaseOptions).then(realm => {
        // realm.create('Config', newConfig);
        // resolve(newConfig);
        console.log(realm);
    }).catch((error) => reject(error))
});
```

I'm calling `insertNewConfig` from here,

```
let config = {
    key: 'instanceUrl',
    value: 'myurl.domain.value'
};

insertNewConfig(config).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});

this.props.navigation.navigate('Login', {});
```

The error is there at the `Realm.open(databaseOptions)` line. First I though the error was with `realm.create` but later realized the original line.

The error showing is like this.

```
Error: _constructor must be of type 'function', got (undefined)
    at sendRequest (rpc.js:263)
    at Object.createRealm (rpc.js:62)
    at new Realm (index.js:102)
    at Function.open (extensions.js:110)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (MetroClient.js:63), <anonymous>:29:22)
    at tryCallTwo (core.js:45)
    at doResolve (core.js:200)
    at new Promise (core.js:66)
    at insertNewConfig (eval at <anonymous> (MetroClient.js:63), <anonymous>:28:12)
    at Object.SelectInstanceScreen._this.continueLogin [as onPress] (eval at <anonymous> (MetroClient.js:63), <anonymous>:74:37)
```

Seems that the `open()` function must be called as a function (_constructor must be of type 'function') but it is obvious that `open()` is called as a function.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I think maybe is a bug on last release (2.18.0), try to downgrade to 2.16.0 it will works.

Answer (score 1):

It is related from last version of realm(v2.18.0). You should downgrade to 2.16.0.

After that, you can run this code for reset all packages;

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && yarn cache clean && yarn install && yarn start -- --reset-cache
```

Comment: Thank you! I moved away from Realm because of this for the time being. But seems like this is the error with the mentioned version itself.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed package.json changed

from `"realm": "ˆ2.16.0",`

to `"realm": "2.16.0",`

And then execute `npm install` or `yarn`

Solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues related to Node update and realm. Realm doesn't work with Node 10 and for your issue downgrading to 2.16 will resolve the issue.